# How can I route Host traffic through Guest VM?

Tags: routing, openwrt

I am wanting to test out OpenWRT, and I am using VirtualBox on windows to muck around with it. Is there anyway I can route the host traffic through the guest openwrt VM?

The openWRT VM has the lan nic set to 'Internal-Network'
the wan nic is bridged.

Even if I set the host up on the new network (valid IP, gateway etc) I still can't see the Guest.

Answer (score 1):

Change the gateway on your windows host to the ip address of your virtualized OpenWRT.  Make sure that your OpenWRT is set to forward packets.  There maybe some setup you need to do on your VirtualBox VM network adapter settings to share the network card on your host, unless you  have multiple network interfaces, and can dedicate one to your OpenWRT vm.